# dotnet complains WindowsDesktop is missing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mono

On Ubuntu 23.04 with dotnet 7.0.105 I try to build a C# project (in Mono):

```
dotnet build 'appname'.csproj
```

which results in the error message:

> MSBuild version 17.4.3+7e646be43 for .NET
> Determining projects to restore...
> All projects are up-to-date for restore.
> /usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.105/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(1226,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.105/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop.targets" was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration
> ";/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.105/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/../../Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop/targets/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop.targets" is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

Build FAILED.

It is correct that `/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop` is missing in the `/usr/lib/dotnet/sdk/7.0.105/Sdks` directory. That is not surprising as WindowsDesktop is obsolete and removed from 7.0.105.
The file `'appname'.csproj` starts with the line `<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">` which should be correct.

What can I do further?

Comment: Run `dotnet --info`. Do you have a "Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App" entry in the .Net runtimes section? You've tagged this "mono" - I don't think that's correct.

Comment: Does your project have an `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`, or `<UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes, it has that line.

Comment: @gunr2171 No, that app is not present, only Microsoft.AspNetCore.App and Microsoft.NETCore.App.  mono has been tagged because Mono is installed and the full command reads  Mono dotnet build 'appname'.csproj

Comment: You can't build WinForms/WPF on non-Windows.

Comment: @gunr2171  I am sorry, the full command is without Mono. I use a directory Mono.

Comment: @CodeCaster That is new to me. According to documentation you should be able to use WinForms through connecting the library by  -r:System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: Which documentation?

Comment: @CodeCaster  
https://markheath.net/post/running-windows-forms-on-linux-with-mono

Comment: That is a nine year old blog post, predating .NET 7 and .NET Core. It targets the full Framework. `dotnet build` is not .NET Framework, it's .NET.

Comment: Waste no more time on WinForms, https://halfblood.pro/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea unless you are on Windows.